# Install fonts on angular 2 page

Tags: css, fonts, angular

I have an Angular 2 application in which i  wish to use wrapbootstrap. I do however have a problem with the fonts (bootstrap, font-awesome, google) as i do not know how to implement them.

When using the css file for wrapbootstrap is says it cannot find font awesome:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8000/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0"

I cannot make sense of this as i can see the missing file(s) in resources in the chrome console on that exact address.

[image]

The font files are currently in a folder vi the following relative path from the css (application.css) file using them:

[image]

Which fits the required path in the css file:

[image]

I hope someone out there can provide some guidance as i am lost.

Thanks in advance

**Solved**
the problem was apparently the location of my fonts folder. 
my file structure are as follows: 
[image]

and i had firstly added the fonts/ relative to where the application.css file was. It had to be located in the root of my app (src)

Comment: it all depends on your folders structure and type of server, which you are using..
Can you create a project on a Plunker (or fiddle)?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, and help - i have solved my problem now

Answer (score 0):

Adding fonts installed with package manager is quite often a task. For instance, using font-awesome or any other similar library is a typical task one will need.

For this purpose, you can go through the following steps:

1. In `tools/config/project.config.ts`:

   ```
   ...
       export class ProjectConfig extends SeedConfig {
           PROJECT_TASKS_DIR = join(process.cwd(), this.TOOLS_DIR, 'tasks', 'project');

           FONTS_DEST = `${this.APP_DEST}/fonts`;
           FONTS_SRC = [
               'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**'
           ];
   ...
   ```
2. Create a file `tools/tasks/project/build.fonts.ts`:

   ```
   import * as gulp from 'gulp';
   import Config from '../../config';

   export = () => {
     return gulp.src(Config.FONTS_SRC)
           .pipe(gulp.dest(Config.FONTS_DEST));
   };
   ```
3. In `gulpfile.ts` (or in `seed.tasks.json` for newer versions of the Seed)

   ```
   // Build dev.
   gulp.task('build.dev', done =>
     runSequence('clean.dev',
                 'tslint',
                 'build.assets.dev',
                 'build.fonts',    // Added task;
                 'build.js.dev',
                 'build.index.dev',
                 done));
   // Build prod.
   gulp.task('build.prod', done =>
     runSequence('clean.prod',
                 'tslint',
                 'build.assets.prod',
                 'build.fonts',    // Added task;
                 'build.html_css.prod',
                 'build.js.prod',
                 'build.bundles',
                 'build.bundles.app',
                 'build.index.prod',
                 done));
   // Build test.
   gulp.task('build.test', done =>
     runSequence('clean.dev',
                 'tslint',
                 'build.assets.dev',
                 'build.fonts',    // Added task;
                 'build.js.test',
                 'build.index.dev',
                 done));
   ```

[src](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Add-external-fonts)